# Software for bridging my computer and a VPS

Tags: windows, linux, internet, vpn, vpn-server

I am not that much of a tech guy so I don't know how to call that software. Basically I am looking for a software that would bridge a connection from my VPS (which has a public IP address) to my computer (which does not have a public IP address) for hosting a game server for example (the VPS itself does not have enough CPU power to handle it).

Something like Hamachi but the connection would be transfered from VPS to my computer and vice versa.

My computer is running Windows and VPS is running Debian.
Thanks

Comment: Your router should have a public IP too. You just need to tell the router to which computer to forward the traffic from the specific port(s) that the gameserver needs (you should remove the port forwarding if you don't need it anymore). If you need a static address, use a dynamic dns service.

Comment: Openvpn from your machine to VPS and port forward